# AudioKit AKSequencer does not loop on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

The following code plays multiple audio files in a loop in iOS 11 but not in iOS 10. Seems like that AKSequencer cannot loop in iOS 10?

```
let mixer = AKMixer()
var sequencer: AKSequencer = AKSequencer()
sequencer.loadMIDIFile(fromUrl: URL(fileURLWithPath: midiFile))

for index in 0..<sequencer.tracks.count {
    let musicTrack: AKMusicTrack = sequencer.tracks[index]
    let sampler = AKMIDISampler()

    if index < samples.count {
        sampler.loadWavFromAbsolutePath(samples[index])
        sampler.enableMIDI(midi.client, name: "Sampler_\(index)")
        mixer.connect(input: sampler)
    }
    musicTrack.setMIDIOutput(sampler.midiIn)
}

AudioKit.output = mixer
AudioKit.start()
sequencer.enableLooping()
sequencer.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what connection this might have to iOS 10, but I've had issues in the past where `AKSequencer` didn't loop when the its `.play()` call followed immediately after `AudioKit.start()`.  I found that putting the `.play()` call in an IBAction or calling it from a timer (delayed 100ms or so) allowed it to loop properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the problem was related to the scope of the `AKSequencer` property.

It looks like the sequencer gets de-initialized and cannot process the MIDI signals any further.

Try to to upgrade the var sequencer: `AKSequencer = AKSequencer()` to a global variable.